# Replace 2nd Screen / Route in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I have this routing situation(using dynamic routes)

User can open a Screen2 by:

```
final route = MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Screen2(name: some_name),
);
Navigator.push(context, route);
```

It can be opened from differen parts of the app, not only from MainScreen.

now I have some logic inside MainScreen( reveiving an intent notification with parameters) and I want that user gets navigating to Screen2 by

- If screen2 is opened -> Replace it with new Screen2
- If screen2 is not opened -> Open new Screen2

Is there a way to make it work?
I tried with pushReplacement

```
final route = MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => Screen2(name: some_name),
);
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
```

but then MainScreen getting replaced, if Screen2 was not opened before.

any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to memorize routes pushed in your navigator stack.

You can put an observer inside your navigator :

Create an instance of NavigationHistoryObserver and put it inside your navigatorObserver, then use its history attributes ;).

Check if a route is present in the history :

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; //firstWhereOrNull

if (your_navigation_history_observer_instance.history.firstWhereOrNull(
      (Route<dynamic> element) =>
          element.settings.name == ProgressDialog.routeName,
    ) != null) {
    ...
    }
```

Your MaterialApp

```dart
navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[
  your_navigation_history_observer_instance,
]
```

The file is a little big, it handle more logic for me:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class NavigationHistoryObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  /// A list of all the past routes
  final List<Route<dynamic>?> _history = <Route<dynamic>?>[];

  /// Gets a clone of the navigation history as an immutable list.
  Iterable<Route<dynamic>> get history => List<Route<dynamic>>.from(_history);

  /// Gets the top route in the navigation stack.
  Route<dynamic>? get top => _history.last;

  /// A list of all routes that were popped to reach the current.
  final List<Route<dynamic>?> _poppedRoutes = <Route<dynamic>?>[];

  /// Gets a clone of the popped routes as an immutable list.
  Iterable<Route<dynamic>> get poppedRoutes =>
      List<Route<dynamic>>.from(_poppedRoutes);

  /// Gets the next route in the navigation history, which is the most recently popped route.
  Route<dynamic>? get next => _poppedRoutes.last;

  /// A stream that broadcasts whenever the navigation history changes.
  final StreamController<dynamic> _historyChangeStreamController =
      StreamController<dynamic>.broadcast();

  /// Accessor to the history change stream.
  Stream<dynamic> get historyChangeStream =>
      _historyChangeStreamController.stream;

  void dispose() {
    _historyChangeStreamController.close();
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    _poppedRoutes.add(_history.last);
    _history.removeLast();
    _historyChangeStreamController.add(
      HistoryChange(
        action: NavigationStackAction.pop,
        newRoute: route,
        oldRoute: previousRoute,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    _history.add(route);
    _poppedRoutes.remove(route);
    _historyChangeStreamController.add(
      HistoryChange(
        action: NavigationStackAction.push,
        newRoute: route,
        oldRoute: previousRoute,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    _history.remove(route);
    _historyChangeStreamController.add(
      HistoryChange(
        action: NavigationStackAction.remove,
        newRoute: route,
        oldRoute: previousRoute,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic>? newRoute, Route<dynamic>? oldRoute}) {
    final int oldRouteIndex = _history.indexOf(oldRoute);
    _history.replaceRange(
      oldRouteIndex,
      oldRouteIndex + 1,
      <Route<dynamic>?>[newRoute],
    );
    _historyChangeStreamController.add(
      HistoryChange(
        action: NavigationStackAction.replace,
        newRoute: newRoute,
        oldRoute: oldRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// A class that contains all data that needs to be broadcasted through the history change stream.
class HistoryChange {
  HistoryChange({this.action, this.newRoute, this.oldRoute});

  final NavigationStackAction? action;
  final Route<dynamic>? newRoute;
  final Route<dynamic>? oldRoute;
}

enum NavigationStackAction { push, pop, remove, replace }
```